# Wordpress site not reflecting Javascript changes

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, caching

So I'm trying to make some changes to the javascript of my company's Wordpress [site](https://cabinedit.com), and have noticed that despite me clicking "publish" in the online editor the site's javascript refuses to update.

I've looked elsewhere for some troubleshooting tips, and have tried the Chrome "empty cache and hard reload" trick, swapping browsers, and changing my enqueue function to give the .js a random version on every load but nothing seems to be working (new enqueue function below). If anyone has any other tips or tricks for remedying this they'd be much appreciated!

wp_enqueue_script('no6-2014', 'jquery', array(), date("h:i:s"));

Comment: check if there's a cache plugin installed

Comment: Thanks for the reply - unfortunately there aren't any.

Comment: there is a js error on your page http://joxi.ru/brRzqLytJbBRLr  Javascript won't work before fixing it